# Conjecture: Is it true that the limiting diameter of a (strictly !) nested family of compact sets must be 0 ??

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Consider a family of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n, C_1 \supset C_2 \supset C_3 \ldots$.

Also, and this is the important bit,

**1) $C_j$ has empty interior for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$**

**2) The inclusions are strictly decreasing, that is $C_i \neq C_j \; \forall i \neq j$**

Can we then prove that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\;\mathrm{diam}(C_k) = 0$ ?

Comment: What if $C_i = \{(a,0,0,0,\ldots,0)\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid |a|\leq 1+\frac{1}{i}\}$?

Comment: That works ! Thank you. If you care to write it up as an answer, I can mark it solved.

Comment: In one dimension, consider the nested closed subsets of $[0,1]$ whose intersection is the Cantor Set.

Comment: In $A_j=\{1,0\}\cup \{1/m: j<m\in \Bbb N\}.$ In $\Bbb R$ let $C_j=A_j.$ For $n>1$ let $C_j=A_j\times \{0\}^{n-1}.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{R}^m$,$m> 1$,and $C_n = [0, \frac{n+1}{n}]\times \{0\}^{m-1}$. For one dimension we can take decreasing Cantor sets in $[0,1]$ that all contain $0$ and $1$ (so have diameter $1$).

Comment: These sets don’t have empty interior.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin you’re right. I misread as non-empty.

Comment: You can use those for higher dimensions (append $0$s); for one dimension, I would use the sets whose intersection makes up the Cantor Set. They are all closed and bounded.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The Cantor set intermediate stages do not have empty interior either.

Comment: Urgh; of course they don’t. But you can probably start with the Cantor set and just remove pieces of it, ending with $\{0,1\}$.